# clustering using k-means/ k-means++, for data with geolocation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, geostatistics

I need to define spatial domains over various types of data collected in my field of study. Each collection is performed at a georeferenced point.

So I need to define the spatial domains through clustering. And generate a map with the domains defined in the georeferenced points. Grateful.

Good. I have jupyter notebook, pandas, scikit-learn, openpyxl installed.[Image A. georeferenced points in the study area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdAoV.png)
[Image B. example of map generated by GS+ on NDVI data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovYHE.png)
[Image C. example of the data I have in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq6t6.png)

Edit: I added the code, which I managed to run

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('areafoliartotal.xlsx')

display(data)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_data = pca.fit_transform(data)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(pca_data)

plt.scatter(pca_data[:, 0], pca_data[:, 1], c=kmeans.labels_)
plt.title('PCA with KMeans Clustering')
plt.xlabel('PC1')
plt.ylabel('PC2')
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKFAC.png)

start with the basics, but like all beginners it is difficult to understand everything. Discover this method of defining spatial domains through this article [EVALUATION OF CLUSTERING TECHNIQUES FOR DEFINING STATIONARY DOMAINS SUPPORTED BY GEOSTATISTICS](https://abmproceedings.com.br/ptbr/article/avaliao-de-tccnicas-de-agrupamento-para-definio-de-dom-nios-estacionrios-com-o-aux-lio-de-geoestat-stica)

Comment: Quite the tale. But what is your question?

Comment: I need to define the spatial domains through clustering. And generate a map with the domains defined in the georeferenced points. Maps similar to the ones I uploaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It looks like your question is "can someone please write me some code?" - and that's not what StackOverflow is for. Please share what you tried, be specific about the problem you're having and ask an actual question about that.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters: you need to edit your question to share your code and ask a more directed question. In the meantime, you have some learning to do. I recommend following a tutorial for a package like [`verde`](https://github.com/fatiando/verde), e.g. [this one](https://www.fatiando.org/tutorials/notebooks/gravity-processing.html). It will get you a very long way.

Comment: I added the code, which I managed to run

Comment: @matt-hall the link you sent, is exactly what I need. For KMeans++ results to be distributed directly over each coordinate. I will try to do it here. Grateful.